# Как скрыть то, что exe файл является sfx архивом

Tags: python, 7z, winrar

Моя скомпилированная пайтон программа имеет много файлов помимо exe(компиляция в один файл делает программу нерабочей). Нужно чтобы при открытии свойств exe файла не было никаких вкладок связанных с архивом вкладок, а также права не принадлежали 7z/WinRar

Comment: Не компилируйте свою пайтон программу тогда.

Answer (score 0):

Этого сделать нельзя без потери работоспособности.